# Maven do not execute script extern in clean phase but only in compile or install

Tags: java, shell, maven, command, executable

With maven I set up a plugin that runs an external script.

```
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Execute External Command</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>
                                ${basedir}/external.sh
                            </executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The problem is that it also starts with the **mvn clean** command. Is it possible not to start the plugin in clean phase? or is it possible to parameterize my external script with a parameter that makes me understand that I am in the clean phase?

Something like:

```
                        <executable>
                            ${basedir}/external.sh ${phase}
                        </executable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change the phase in your plugin, for exmple:

```
  <phase>install</phase>
```

full plugin:

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Execute External Command</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>
                            ${basedir}/external.sh
                        </executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

you can choose any of the other suitable phases.